# Jointjs type definition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, jointjs, type-definition

I'm newbe in typescript and trying to use jointjs definition file with typescript 2.2.

this is definition file in github.
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jointjs/index.d.ts

to import jointjs to my typescript file i use

```
import { joint } from 'jointjs';
```

How can I call classes and functions from index.d.ts file?

Comment: How is your project setup? If you're using modules, [jointjs has its own type defs](https://github.com/clientIO/joint/blob/master/dist/joint.d.ts) (that are newer) so you don't need DT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JointJS library comes with the type definitions so you don't have to install separate typings, just `npm install --save jointjs` will be enough. And then you can use import and use the library like:

```
import * as joint from 'jointjs';

let circle = new joint.shapes.basic.Circle();
```

Comment: Thanks for your concern,I have installed it but get Cannot find type definition file for 'backbone'

Comment: I have installed backbone by npm install --save @types/backbone  but get same error

Comment: Solved after restart

Answer (score 0):

You can get all your class elements and functions by using joint .

```
var paper = this.paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
                width: 1000,
                height: 1000,
                gridSize: 10,
                drawGrid: true,
                model: graph,
                defaultLink: new joint.shapes.app.Link,
                defaultConnectionPoint: joint.shapes.app.Link.connectionPoint,
                interactive: { linkMove: false }
            });
```